# Youtube video problem

Tags: 16.04, youtube

I'm experiencing a Youtube [HTML5] video playback problem on Ubuntu 16.04. I have an Intel HD Grahics. Problem is that the video is choppy. For example, when in video there's fast movement or something, it cuts the screen in half for a second, you can barely see it, but you can notice it. I tried enabling/disabling hardware acceleration, but I can't fix it. It is happening both in Google Chrome and in Firefox.

Intel HD Graphics Bay Trail - Intel Pentium N3540

Comment: HTML5 or Flash?

Comment: I think it's HTML5

Comment: Confirm by right-clicking on any video and look at the "About" line. When you do please edit your question and add that detail. Also add hardware specs, i.e., which "Intel HD Graphics".

Comment: It is an Intel HD Graphics Bay Trail and the CPU is Intel Pentium N3540. And yes, it is HTML5